# where do I put the files when I download adventure maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I am having trouble knowing where you put the files of adventure maps. I couldn't find anything of where to put the files once they are downloaded in the description. Where do I put the files of adventure maps so that I can play them?

Answer (score 4):

Worlds are saved in your `%appdata%\.minecraft\saves` folder on Windows, `~/.minecraft/saves` on Linux, or `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves` on Mac OSX.

Comment: Never mind, I have figured it out on my own.